# What kind of question should be asked on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, migration, asking-questions, scope

If there are websites for each topic/field separately e.g. Linux and Unix, askubuntu etc., then what type of questions should be asked on stackoverflow.com?

I am asking this because once my question on Stack Overflow was downvoted and it was suggested that I should migrate this question to an other domain.

Comment: What question do you mean? What was the confusion? If it is within the borders of http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , there is no specific need to go to another domain, but if you ask "how do I install ubuntu", it is clearly offtopic here, and the suggestion is correct

Comment: If you're referring to [this (deleted) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685116/how-to-add-more-spce-to-root-and-home-directory), that was not a programming question, but one about more general computer usage. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387184/how-to-install-netbeans-6-x-in-ubuntu-13-04) is a little more borderline, because it concerns the installation of a programming-related library, but the question seems to be more about the installation process.

Comment: Questions about programming.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, trying to get back on topic. Even if for most of us the difference seems obvious (and not all that hard to find) it's good to see you take the effort, rather than blindly continue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information is readily available from the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), which is a strongly advised reading before creating a new question on any Stack Exchange site.

[image]

Check the [section regarding on topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4):

Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

> a specific programming problem
>   a software algorithm
>   software tools commonly used by programmers
>   practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development

And here you find what you should *not* ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Before posting a question, you should also have a look at the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/229438)

Answer (score 2):

Every Stack Exchange site has a help section. You can find it by clicking *"help"* on the top navigation bar beside the search box:

[image]

From there, you'll find everything you need including a link to *"What topics can I ask about here?"*

Here are some you were asking about:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)
- [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)